# Domain join with bicep file in azure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-bicep, azure-vm

I'm creating an azure vm and having issues joining it to a domain and it appears to be around tcp/ip v6  being enabled.  How do I disable v6 in the bicep file on creation so I can using Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions to auto join to my domain?

Using Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces to create my nic and Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines to create my vm.

On further discovery I can after all join once I get the machine booted up.
Here is my bicep section I am using to join the domain:

```
resource virtualMachineExtension 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions@2021-03-01' = {
  parent: windowsVm
  name: 'joindomain'
  location: location
  properties: {
    publisher: 'Microsoft.Compute'
    type: 'JsonADDomainExtension'
    typeHandlerVersion: '1.3'
    autoUpgradeMinorVersion: true
    settings: {
      name: 'corp.mydomain.com'
      ouPath: 'Servers,DC=corp,DC=mydomain,DC=com'
      user: 'corp.mydomain.com\\${domainJoinUserName}'
      restart: true
      options: 3
    }
    protectedSettings: {
      Password: domainJoinUserPassword
    }
  }
}
```

I capture the username and password with a deploy script that includes:

```
$domainJoinUserName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Domain Admin Username'
    $domainJoinUserPassword = Read-Host -AsSecureString -Prompt 'Domain Admin Password'
    $domainJoinUserPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($domainJoinUserPassword))
```